# Applying Custom Shaders to a GeoJSON in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, webgl, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to apply a custom style using shaders to a GeoJSON layer in Mapbox GL.

I saw the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-layer/) on custom styles with shaders and successfully reproduced the simple example provided.

I also managed to pass the geojson coordinates as parameters instead of harcoded points as in the example. However, I only get a triangle rendered on the map, instead of the form of the GeoJSON. Because of `gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP` in the render function.

I'm not familiarised with WebGL. I did check [this lesson](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-points-lines-triangles.html) from WebGL fundamentals to try to understand a bit more.

How could the render function be adapted to get the actual GeoJSON shape with shaders style? Below is the general function I'm using to create the layer based on the array of coordinates from the GeoJSON.

```
function getShaderLayer(coordinatesArray){
    const highlightLayer = {
        id: 'highlight',
        type: 'custom',
         
        // method called when the layer is added to the map
        // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#styleimageinterface#onadd
        onAdd: function (map, gl) {
            // create GLSL source for vertex shader
            const vertexSource = `
            uniform mat4 u_matrix;
            attribute vec2 a_pos;
            void main() {
                gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_pos, 0.0, 1.0);
            }`;
            
            // create GLSL source for fragment shader
            const fragmentSource = `
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5); 
            }`; // tem que se chamar gl_FragColor obrigatoriamente
            
            // create a vertex shader
            const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexSource);
            gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
            
            // create a fragment shader
            const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentSource);
            gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
            
            // link the two shaders into a WebGL program
            this.program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(this.program, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(this.program, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(this.program);
            
            this.aPos = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_pos');

            let pointsArray = [];
            for (let i=0; i < coordinatesArray.length; i++){
                let point = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
                    lng: coordinatesArray[i][0],
                    lat: coordinatesArray[i][1]
                });
                pointsArray.push(point.x);
                pointsArray.push(point.y);
            }
            const pointsArray32 = new Float32Array(pointsArray)
            console.log(pointsArray32)
            
            // create and initialize a WebGLBuffer to store vertex and color data
            this.buffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);
            gl.bufferData(
                gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                pointsArray32,
                gl.STATIC_DRAW
            );
        },
         
        // method fired on each animation frame
        // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:render
        render: function (gl, matrix) {
            gl.useProgram(this.program);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
                gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_matrix'),
                false,
                matrix
            );
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.aPos);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.aPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
            gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3); // esses negocios em maiuscula sao da webgl api (nao do mapbox)
        }
    };
    return highlightLayer;
}
```